# Is resolving a service in Startup.cs a service locator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I've read [Service Locator: roles vs mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) by Mark Seemann and I can't decide about something. Is this `GetRequiredService` method, which is used in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` (which is the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) if I'm understanding it correctly), a service locator:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddScoped<IRepository, MyRepository>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var myPolicy = services.BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetRequiredService<IRepository>().GetMyPolicy();

        options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.AddRequirements(myPolicy));
    });
}
```

Comment: An article that frames this is [DI Friendly Framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/). A framework must generally supply at least one extension point (usually an abstract factory) where the container can be injected *inside of the composition root*, otherwise it won't know anything about the end user's components. This is not a service locator - it is a reality of integrating with a framework of any kind.

Comment: Big warning here: You should be very careful in calling `BuildServiceProvider`, because that would force the creation of a different container instance with its own set of singletons. This could lead to very weird behavior and hard to trace bugs. Instead, prefer to create the `MyRepository` by hand inside the `AddAuthorization` delegate.

Comment: @Steven: I actually use SimpleInjector I'd be using it for service resolving, I just used native .NET container for the examples sake. Thanks for the warning though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by Mark [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/):

> A DI container encapsulated in a Composition Root is not a Service Locator - it's an infrastructure component.

The `Startup` class is part of the Composition Root. This implies that calling `GetRequiredService` is *not* an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: Definitively you're a fan of Mark Seemann! I've seen you either commenting out whatever or answering questions on which you always use him as your reference :D

Comment: @MatiasFidemraizer: Not a fan at all. But why try to repeat things that are already expressed by others clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm 100% agree with you. When we try to explain some concept using our own words I feel that we're challenging ourselves to validate if we really understand the thing we're attempting to describe. BTW don't get me wrong! I'm not saying your answer is wrong or of low quality. I've just noted that whenever I see you commenting out a Q or A, or answering a question I see you quoting Mark Seemann :D

Answer (score 1):

There're some corner cases where *service locators* are unavoidable.

Not all frameworks or libraries have all its pieces ready to be part of a dependency injection chain, hence you're required to directly use the IoC container to locate the whole service.

Just try to avoid service locators as part of your actual application code on which you're responsible of doing your best in terms of software architecture.